# How do I get SemanticZoom to Zoom to correct area

Tags: semantic-zoom

All the SemanticZoom examples I have look at involve linking to a data source that way on the zoomed out view when you click a category it zooms to the correct location on the zoomed in view.

My problem is I am not displaying data just an interface made of several Grid containing textboxes and textblocks.

I have got the SemanticZoom working visually but when I select a category on the zoom out view it always takes me to the beginning of the zoomed in view.

I know it is doing this because there is no reference in the zoomed out view telling it where to go but I don't know what I have to add for this to work.  My XAML is below quite long:

```
 <SemanticZoom Grid.Row="1">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <GridView  IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None">


                    <!-- Length Input Area -->
        <Grid Margin="70,0,70,0" Background="#FFBFFFD9" Width="320" Height="545" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                Various Text Boxes and Textblocks                   
            </Grid>

            <!-- Weight Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,70,0" Background="#FFC7D6FF" Width="320" Height="545">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                 Various Text Boxes and Textblocks                      </Grid>

            <!-- Speed Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,70,0" Background="#FFF0B2BA" Width="320" Height="545">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                 Various Text Boxes and Textblocks                    </Grid>

            <!-- Area Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,70,0" Background="#FFFFFBB0" Width="320" Height="545">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                Various Text Boxes and Textblocks                    </Grid>

            <!-- Volume Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,70,0" Background="#FFFFD9A2" Width="320" Height="545">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                 Various Text Boxes and Textblocks                    </Grid>

            <!-- Fuel Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,70,0" Width="320"  Height="545" Background="#FFAA9C9B">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                Various Text Boxes and Textblocks    
            </Grid>

            <!-- Pressure Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="320" Background="#FFB9F8FB" Height="545">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                Various Text Boxes and Textblocks    
            </Grid>

    </GridView>

        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>

        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
             <GridView  Margin="100,0,0,0"  Height="300" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None">

                    <!-- Length Input Area -->
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFBFFFD9" Width="150" Height="245" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Length" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>
         </Grid>

            <!-- Weight Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFC7D6FF" Width="150" Height="245">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Weight" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>
     </Grid>

            <!-- Speed Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFF0B2BA" Width="150" Height="245">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Speed" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>
       </Grid>

            <!-- Area Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFFFFBB0" Width="150" Height="245">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Area" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>
         </Grid>

            <!-- Volume Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFFFD9A2" Width="150" Height="245">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Volume" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>
        </Grid>

            <!-- Fuel Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150"  Height="245" Background="#FFAA9C9B">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Fuel" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>

            </Grid>

            <!-- Pressure Input Area -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Background="#FFB9F8FB" Height="245">


                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Pressure" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="8,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="40"/>

            </Grid>

    </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```